# Сложить данные из трёх таблиц в четвертую

Tags: mysql

Дано:
три больших таблицы (first, second, third) вида

```
    CREATE TABLE `first` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `chr` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `left` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `right` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;
```

содержащих данные и четвертая (такая же) - пустая.

chr, left, right - сочетание этих трёх параметров уникально, т.е. {1, 4567, 4689} встретится не более одного раза в каждой таблице.
Задача:
Просуммировать поле count всех трёх таблиц для каждого сочетания {chr, left, right} и внести данные в четвёртую таблицу. Причем, возможны ситуации, когда конкретное сочетание не встречается в одной или двух таблицах

Как это сделать сторонними средствами - знаю. Возможно ли сделать это средствами MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это будет что-то вроде

```
CREATE TABLE `forth` (
`chr` int(11) NOT NULL,
`left` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`right` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`count` int(11) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `chr_left_right` (`chr`, `left`, `right`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;

INSERT INTO `forth` (`chr`, `left`, `right`, `count`)
SELECT `chr`, `left`, `right`, `count`
FROM `first`;

INSERT INTO `forth` (`chr`, `left`, `right`, `count`)
SELECT `chr`, `left`, `right`, `count` cnt
FROM `second`
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
`count` = `count` + cnt;

INSERT INTO `forth` (`chr`, `left`, `right`, `count`)
SELECT `chr`, `left`, `right`, `count` cnt
FROM `third`
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
`count` = `count` + cnt;
```

В вопросе не сказано, что делать с полем ID. Но как я понял, это синтетический ключ, значение которого не нужно.

Comment: Да, id - для дальнейшего удобства. Попробовал код, подсвечивает SET после KEY UPDATE как ошибку (Syntax Erros: Unexpected SET (set))

Comment: Ок, поправил...

Comment: Поправлю, совсем уберу неоднозначность... готово, исправлено.

Comment: На всякий случай - уникальный индекс должен стоять в 4 таблице по этим трем полям. Авторские слова "сочетание этих трёх параметров уникально" может не означать, что ее в схеме проставили :)

Comment: Работают оба подхода, и Ваш, и tcpack5, Результаты идентичны :)  Только Ваш быстрее -  75 секунд супротив 287. Плюс с удовольствием ставлю, но мой рейтинг пока не 15.

Comment: @tcpack4 *На всякий случай - уникальный индекс должен стоять в 4 таблице по этим трем полям.* Я именно поэтому дал код создания четвёртой таблицы - с созданием уникального индекса.

Comment: @ВикторТомилов *Работают оба подхода* Обычное дело. *Ваш быстрее* И чем пухлее таблицы, тем больше будет профит.

Answer (score 2):

Вот так:

```
INSERT INTO fourth (`chr`, `left`, `right`, `count`)
select chr, left,right, SUM (count) as sum_
from (select chr, left,right, count
from first
union all 
select chr, left,right, count
from second
union all 
select chr, left,right, count
from third) 
group by chr, left,right
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот таким образом можно сделать:

```
INSERT INTO summary (`chr`, `left`, `right`, `count`)
SELECT `chr`, `left`, `right`, SUM(`count`) FROM (
    SELECT `chr`, `left`, `right`, `count` FROM first 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `chr`, `left`, `right`, `count` FROM second 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `chr`, `left`, `right`, `count` FROM third
) s
```

Comment: Запрос неверен. Если в таблицах есть полные дубликаты - потеряете данные. Следует использовать `UNION ALL` (см. ответ by ***Novitskiy Denis***). И я бы рекомендовал вместо звёзд указывать конкретные поля - если структура таблиц не совпадает по порядку полей, получится неверный результат или ошибка несоответствия типов.

Comment: если есть полные дубликаты они будут суммироваться.

Comment: Они отсеются ещё до суммирования, при объединении по UNION DISTINCT. И на суммирование попадёт только один экземпляр записи.

Comment: @Akina на этапе UNION будут все дубликаты. Можете проверить.

Comment: @Akina для наглядности https://pastebin.com/2Lb4zBPi.

Comment: Я же русским по белому сказал - ПОЛНЫЕ дубликаты!!! А у Вас поле *count* - различается. Вставьте в каждую из трёх таблиц запись, где все пять полей - единица. И любуйтесь на результат.

Comment: @Akina ок, поправил. Сорян. Подумал про "полные дубликаты" - это в контексте уник. индекса по трем полям. Если бы сказали "все поля", то яснее было бы)

Comment: Работают оба подхода, и Ваш с небольшими правками, и Akina, Результаты идентичны :)  Только Ваш медленнее - 287 секунд супротив 75. Плюс с удовольствием ставлю, но мой рейтинг пока не 15.